# Foreach List não reconhece array

Tags: php, foreach

Estou usando *PHP*.
Passo os valores por `_POST`, e tenho uma string, que transformei em array:

Pelo método _POST ela chega assim:

```
[1v4],,,,[5v3],,,[8v]
```

Removo as vírgulas em excesso, tiro o separador 'v' e transformo ela em array com os comandos abaixo:

```
$valors = $_POST['valors'];
$array = str_replace(",","",$valors);
$array1 = str_replace("v",",",$array);
$array2 = str_replace("]","],-",$array1);
$arr = explode('-', $array2);
```

Saída pelo var_dump da variável $arr:

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> string(6) "[1,4],"
[1]=> string(6) "[5,3],"
[2]=> string(5) "[8,],"
[3]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

Saída pelo foreach simples:

```
[1,4],
[5,3],
[8,],
```

Mas quando tento fazer um foreach list, os valores das variaveis A e B retornam nulo:

```
foreach ($arr as list($a, $b)) {
    echo "A: $a; B: $b\n<br>";
}
```

E já não sei mais o que fazer, para separar os dois valores nas variáveis...

Comment: Para lhe responder com segurança precisamos da `string` que está convertendo e do método ou função de conversão.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, dados solicitados adicionados.

Comment: O problema está no método que gera o array `$arr`. Esses elementos de `$arr`: `[1,4],`, `[5,3],` e `[8,],` foram gerados equivocadamente como `strings` e não `arrays`. `list()` só funciona sobre array. Então a cada iteração de `foreach ($arr as list($a, $b))` ele está iterando sobre uma `string` de `$arr` por isso `$a`e `$b` são nulos.

Comment: Sugiro que faça a limpeza do array dentro do foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deve ter jeito mais simples de se fazer, mas deste jeito irá atender:

```
$valores = '[1v4],,,,[5v3],,,[8v]'; //Post no seu caso
$array = explode(',',$valores); //já que não vai usar a virgula, pode explodir ela mesma.
$array = array_filter($array); //remove todos os campos vazios de um array
$array = array_values($array); //remove todos os campos vazios de um array
$array = str_replace('v',',', $array);
$remover = ['[',']'];
$array = str_replace($remover,'', $array);

foreach ($array as $a => $b) {
  $partes = explode(',',$b);
  $a = $partes[0];
  $b = $partes[1]
  echo "A: $a; B: $b\n<br>";
}
```

//resultado
A: 1; B: 4
A: 5; B: 3
A: 8; B:

Comment: Obrigado a todos, com as informações prestadas o código funcionou  :)

Comment: Magina, pratique para simplificar ainda mais esse código ;)